# Dejar almacenados los datos que envío de ionic a firebase sin que se borren

Tags: firebase, ionic3, geolocalización

tengo un problema al almacenar mis coordenadas (latitud y longitud) en firebase, estas las mando de una aplicación en ionic, las coordenadas las almacena en segundo plano de la misma manera, pero al momento de forzar el cierre de la aplicación e iniciar sesión de nuevo en esta. Firebase me coloca en 0 las coordenadas (latitud y longitud).
Lo que quiero es que estos datos se queden almacenados en Firebase, aunque cierre sesión, apague el equipo o lo reinicie y a partir de esos datos seguir almacenando los siguientes.
Este es el código de cómo almaceno las coordenadas en Firebase.

```
  //empieza geololaizacion
start() { 


   // Compruebo si esta habilidata la opcion de localizacion
  this.backgroundGeolocation.isLocationEnabled()
  .then((activado) =>{
      //si esta activado
    if(activado){

      let config = {
        desiredAccuracy: 0,
        stationaryRadius: 0,
        distanceFilter: 0,
        debug: false,
        interval: 0
      };
      //Geolocalizacion en segundo Plano      
      this.backgroundGeolocation
      .configure(config)
      .subscribe((location) => {
        console.log("latitud actualizacion background 1 "+location.latitude);
        let  _date: Date = new Date();
        let n: number = _date.getTime();
        n -= (_date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000);
        let d: string = new Date(n).toISOString();

        this.zone.run(() => {
        this.lat = location.latitude;
        this.lng = location.longitude;
        });
        this.actuario.update({
            lat: this.lat,
            lng: this.lng,
        });
           this.markes.push({
             latitud: this.lat,
             longitud: this.lng,
              date: d
           });
          let markes = this.markes;
           this.actuario.set({
               markes
            }, { merge: true })
                   .then(function() {})
                   .catch(function(error) {
                   console.log("Error al subir datos! " + error);
             });


        });

      // start recording location
      this.backgroundGeolocation.start();
    //  this.backgroundMode.disableWebViewOptimizations();
      let options = {
        frequency: 300000,
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout:300000
    };
        //cuando la aplicacion esta abierta y activada
      this.watch = this.geolocation.watchPosition(options).filter((p: any) => p.code === undefined)
      .subscribe((position: Geoposition) => {
        console.log("latitud actualizacion 2 "+position.coords.latitude + "  " + position.coords.longitude);
      let  _date: Date = new Date();
        let n: number = _date.getTime();
        n -= (_date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000);
        let d: string = new Date(n).toISOString();

       //actualizo dato en firebase
        this.actuario.update({
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude
          });
          //para poder mapear en un mapa se guardan los datos
             this.markes.push({
               latitud:position.coords.latitude,
               longitud:position.coords.longitude,
               date:d
             });
             let markes = this.markes;
             this.actuario.set({markes}, { merge: true })
                     .then(function() {})
                     .catch(function(error) {
                     console.log("Error al subir datos! " + error);
               });
      });

    }else {
      this.backgroundGeolocation.showLocationSettings();
    }
  }) 
}
```

Comment: Porque tenés geolocalizacion cuando la app esta en segundo plano y cuando la app esta en primer plano ??? Y tienes a ambas opciones haciendo lo mismo?

Comment: La idea es seguir guardando las coordenadas en firebase, cuando el usuario interactua con la aplicacion  utilizo watchPosition,  cuando el usuario sale de la aplicacion o se bloque el telefono utilizo backgroundGeolocation, hay otra forma de hacer esto ?